# different css formatting on different <p> tags

Tags: asp.net, html, css

i am creating a website where i read in html data from other websites.

The problem is that the source that i am reading all has `<p>` tags in it, but i actually want to format them differently

is there a way to have some `<p>` tags using one formatting and some `<p>` tags do other formatting in the same web page?

Comment: Can you format the source content that is being read from the other site?

Comment: Will the imported p tags have inline styling applied?

Comment: Can you supply example source code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap the imported content with something like this:

```
<div class='imported'>
<p>Imported content here...</p>
<p>These paragraph tags were imported...</p>
</div>
```

and style it like this:

```
div.imported p {
    /* My style for imported <p>s */
}
```

**Edit** In answer to the comment about styling your own `<p>`s, you can style all the `<p>`s on the page with a standard rule like this:

```
p {
    /* Style for all <p>s */
}
```

and then the more specific rule for imported `<p>`s will override that one.

**Edit**: In answer to the comment about inline styles, you could override them with `!important` but that will have a knock-on effect on people with user style sheets.  I don't believe there's a clean CSS-only solution to that - you might end up having to parse the imported HTML after all.

Comment: p. importes selects only p tags with class imported and your imported class is attached to a div element. Is this valid?

Comment: But I think he is reading the content from another page and how could he change the html of the content.

Comment: @phoenix: He doesn't need to change the content - he wraps it in a `<div class='imported'>` when he inserts it into his page. The paragraphs in my example are the unchanged imported HTML.

Comment: But what if the imported p tags have inline styles associated with them.

Comment: You're not answering the question: one formatting for a <p> and another formatting for a different <p>.

Comment: @CsTamas: He can style his own `<p>`s in the usual way; I thought that would go without saying.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if the tags have different CSS classes, e.g.

#### HTML

```
<p class="foo-site">This is some content lifted from Foo Site.</p>
<p class="bar-site">This is some content lifted from Bar Site.</p>
```

#### CSS

```
p.foo {
    /* Style for Foo Site text */
}

p.bar {
    /* Style for Bar Site text */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<div class="includedContent">
<p>a paragraph</p>
</div>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
```

with

```
p { font-size: 8pt; }
div.includedContent p { font-size: 10pt; }
```

Comment: For screen media the pt unit is considered harmful (it breaks font scaling in IE, and most systems are not configured to calculate points correctly). Please don't use it in examples.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can probably give them specificity like so

```
p:first-child { /* note this won't work in ie6 */
    border: 1px solid red;
}

p.main {
    background: pink;
}
```

If you don't have access to change the HTML, and REALLY needed to add classes (to get it to work in IE6), you could use jQuery (keep in mind users without JS won't see any of your classes added this way)

```
$('#content p:last').addClass('last');
```

Answer (score 1):

There has to be something in the markup to differentiate the paragraphs from each other.

One group might all be a member of a [given class](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_class.htm), or might all be [descendants](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/document_descendant.htm) of an element with a [particular id](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_id.htm), or some [other condition](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/).

You have to look at your markup, see if there are any rules that can describe the group of paragraphs that is different, and change the markup so such a rule can be written if there aren't.

[Selectutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/) will help you learn about the types of rules you can use.

Since you say you are importing HTML from other websites (I hope you are being careful, it sounds like you risk letting them insert harmful code into your pages), you should be able to wrap the imported code in an element (a `div` would probably be best) that you can give a class or an id and use a descendent selector with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to add css to all even and odd `<p>`s like this:

`$("p:even").css("background-color", "#bbbbff");`

`$("p:odd").css("background-color", "#aaaaff");`